# Does salesforce REST API differentiate between expired access\refresh token?

Tags: rest, salesforce

From a client's point of view, when a refresh token has expired it's a much more serious problem than when just the access token has expired. It would be useful  if the salesforce REST API differentiate the two cases and give different error messages so that the client can handle the error accordingly.

It gives this error message called  error when we try to connect to salesforce: { [invalid_grant: expired access/refresh token] name: 'invalid_grant' }

This could happen,  if the access token expires **OR** the refresh token expires.
Is there any way we can find out with the salesforce REST API which token has expired?